# python rpm package no module named main

Tags: python, rpm

I cannot create rpm of my python module, I use setuptools, I create and install my rpm but when I start my program I have this error:

```
ImportError: No module named main
```

My file `/root/myprog/setup.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from myprog import __version__


def read(path):
    with open(path) as fd:
        return fd.read().splitlines()
setup(
  name="myprog",
    version=__version__,

# ...the rest of our setup.py here....

  entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'myprog=myprog:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

my file `/root/myrpog/myprog/__init__.py:`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__program__ = 'myprog'
__version__ = '1.0'
__description__ = 'myprog is new program for linux'
```

my file `/root/myprog/myprog/main.py:`

```
def main():
    main=main()

class main():
    def __init__(self):
        print("toto")
main=main()
```

Comment: I think one of your _main_ issues here is just that; just about everything that you could call "main", you did. The namespace in "main.py" doesn't make sense since `main` inside the function `main()` is invalid, but that gets replaced by the class `main()`. I can actually run your code locally and get "toto" but it's particularly functional code. It's pretty hard to see past these issues to understand the error. What code is throwing the `ImportError`?

Comment: when i execute python setup.py bdist_rpm, i have rpm package.
I installe this with yum install myprog.rpm and it's work.

But when i set "myprog" in th shell, i have this error.
My aim is create rpm package for deploy my app
For test, you must create rpm et install this rpm in your pc, normaly you can not can not strt programm "myprog" and you have this error in bash : ImportError: No module named main

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this setup, the only thing I can suggest is that you have a directory "myprog" inside another directory called "myprog" so is it perhaps looking for "main" in the outer directory?